# De-dupe based if not unique in R

Tags: r

For an example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(postcode = c("ne34rt", "ne34rt", "ne34rt", "ne34rt", 
                                  "cb12sd", "cb23ef", "cb23ef", "cb23ef", "cb46tf"), name = c("katie", 
                                  "katie", "katie", "john", "lucie", "amy", "amy", "amy", "dawn"
                                  ), score = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("postcode", 
                                  "name", "score"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                  -9L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(postcode = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                    "collector")), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                "collector")), score = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                             "collector"))), .Names = c("postcode", "name", "score")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                          "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I wish to delete rows if the name, postcode and score are the same. In the above dataframe, a katie score 5 and amy score 4 would be deleted (as they are the only two rows that are duplicated).

Any ideas? I have been trying to use unique to little success...

Comment: Try `df[!(duplicated(df)|duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `duplicated` from `base R` to create a logical condition

```
df[!(duplicated(df)|duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

In case we want to filter the rows using a subset of columns, apply the `duplicated` on the subset data

```
nm1 <- colnames(df)[1:2]
df[!(duplicated(df[nm1])|duplicated(df[nm1], fromLast = TRUE)),]
```

NOTE: The above removes all the duplicate rows in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to check only for duplicated row's in a couple of columns. In that case, you can use data.table's unique, in which you can enter column-combinations that should be unique.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
unique( dt, by = c("postcode", "name", "score") )

   postcode  name score
1:   ne34rt katie     5
2:   ne34rt katie     4
3:   ne34rt  john     3
4:   cb12sd lucie     6
5:   cb23ef   amy     4
6:   cb23ef   amy     1
7:   cb46tf  dawn     2

unique( dt, by = c("postcode","name") )

   postcode  name score
1:   ne34rt katie     5
2:   ne34rt  john     3
3:   cb12sd lucie     6
4:   cb23ef   amy     4
5:   cb46tf  dawn     2


unique( dt, by = c("postcode") )

   postcode  name score
1:   ne34rt katie     5
2:   cb12sd lucie     6
3:   cb23ef   amy     4
4:   cb46tf  dawn     2
```